# Images not displaying locally after switching from IIS Express to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

I've a website developed in ASP.NET which includes an image:

```
<div id="pictureDiv">
            <img src="/Content/Images/Barry.jpg" style="width:270px;height:330px" />
        </div>
```

When I run this locally using IIS Express the image displays.
When I deploy it to a server hosting it using IIS it also displays
When I set up IIS to run on my local machine it does not display.
If I swap the image src for an absolute source (e.g. http://tinyurl.com/pesd27g) then that works too

So it seems like the relative src reference in the html above works in IISExpress but not in IIS. How can I get it to work?

Comment: not sure,try `src="~/Content/Images/Barry.jpg"`

Comment: thanks, tried that. Didn't work

Comment: Run the site, go into IIS, select the content folder in the left hand `Connections` panel, and then click `Browse *:80 http` in the `Actions` panel out to the right. Tell us what the path to the content folder is from the address bar of your browser. Don't worry if it 403's, we just want to know the path IIS is using to accessing content folder.

Comment: Are you running the site in a virtual directory or in the root of the website?

Answer (score -1):

External URL (as the "tinyurl" in your question) will always work. You should ask yourself 3 questions in the following order:

1. Is my relative URL resolved correctly - you can check it with developer tools in your browser (F12)
2. If the URL is correct, is there a file at the given location in the file system?
3. If the file is present then IIS is not serving it correctly.

Check whether the StaticFile handler is enabled in your IIS. You can find it at `IIS->Site->Handler mappings`.

You can also turn it on in your web.config in `system.webServer/handlers`.

```
<add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```